# Scrapy honor rel=nofollow

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Can scrapy ignore `rel="nofollow"` links?
Looking at the [sgml.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/14179a16a10bd51e81f3f52cc581eaf9dab25382/scrapy/contrib/linkextractors/sgml.py) in `scrapy 0.22` it looks like it does:

How do I enable it?

Comment: `SgmlLinkExtractor` will extract `Link` objects that have a `nofollow` attribute set to `True` or `False`. What do you mean by "does scrapy have respect"? you mean with a `CrawlSpider`?

Comment: @pault. rephrased question.  So I can use a `nofollow= True` in the SgmlLinkExtractor rules?

Comment: One option is to implement a `process_links` function to filter out those `Link` objects that have `nofollow=True`. See [documentation on CrawlSpider Rules](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=crawlspider#crawling-rules) on how to register your callable for `process_links` parameter (`process_links=lambda links: [link for link in links if not link.nofollow]` would work I think)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul's spot on, this is how I did it:

```
rules = (
# Extract all pages, follow links, call method 'parse_page' for response callback, before processing links call method links_processor
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('','/')),follow=True,callback='parse_page',process_links='links_processor'),
```

And this is the actual function (I'm new to python, I'm sure there's a nicer way to remove items from within to for loop without creating a new list

```
def links_processor(self,links): 
 # A hook into the links processing from an existing page, done in order to not follow "nofollow" links 
 ret_links = list()
 if links:
 for link in links:
 if not link.nofollow: ret_links.append(link)
 return ret_links
```

Easy does it.

Answer (score 1):

Itamar Gero's Answer is correct. 
For my own blog I've implemented a CrawlSpider that uses LinkExtractor-based Rules to extract all relevant links from my blog pages:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
*   This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
*   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
*   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
*   (at your option) any later version.
*
*   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
*   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
*   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
*   GNU General Public License for more details.
*
*   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
*   along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*
*   @author Marcel Lange <info@ask-sheldon.com>
*   @package ScrapyCrawler 
 '''


from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

import Crawler.settings
from Crawler.items import PageCrawlerItem


class SheldonSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = Crawler.settings.CRAWLER_NAME
    allowed_domains = Crawler.settings.CRAWLER_DOMAINS
    start_urls = Crawler.settings.CRAWLER_START_URLS
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow_domains=Crawler.settings.CRAWLER_DOMAINS,
                allow=Crawler.settings.CRAWLER_ALLOW_REGEX,
                deny=Crawler.settings.CRAWLER_DENY_REGEX,
                restrict_css=Crawler.settings.CSS_SELECTORS,
                canonicalize=True,
                unique=True
            ),
            follow=True,
            callback='parse_item',
            process_links='filter_links'
        ),
    )

    # Filter links with the nofollow attribute
    def filter_links(self, links):
        return_links = list()
        if links:
            for link in links:
                if not link.nofollow:
                    return_links.append(link)
                else:
                    self.logger.debug('Dropped link %s because nofollow attribute was set.' % link.url)
        return return_links

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # self.logger.info('Parsed URL: %s with STATUS %s', response.url, response.status)
        item = PageCrawlerItem()
        item['status'] = response.status
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//title/text()')[0].extract()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['headers'] = response.headers
        return item
```

On https://www.ask-sheldon.com/build-a-website-crawler-using-scrapy-framework/ I've described detailed how I've implemented a website crawler to warm up my Wordpress fullpage cache.